# rxswift block life cycle

Tags: ios, rx-swift

I have a viewmode class like this :

```
class ViewMode {
 let validateCountResult: Driver<Bool>
 init(username: Driver<String>) {
     validateCountResult = username
            .flatMapLatest { username in
                return // validate username
    }
}
```

And I have a subclass  of `UIViewController` as follow :

```
class ViewController : UIViewController{
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let viewmode = 
        ViewMode(textfiled.rx.texttext.orEmpty.asDriver())
        viewmode.validateCountResult.drive(onNext:{
          // TODO Something
           FuncA()
         })
   }
}
```

When viewDidload finishes, I believe the viewmode should deinits as well. But I see the binding still exists and FuncA still get called!

Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to understand binding is to think of the relationship as a connection between two entities:
A producer, which produces the value。
A receiver, which processes the values from the producer.
A receiver cannot return a value. This is a general rule when using bindings of RxSwift.
The fundamental function of binding is bind(to:), and to bind an observable to another entity it's required that the receiver conforms to ObserverType.

Answer (score 0):

You should dispose your `Disposable` types by creating a `DisposeBag`.

If you don’t, there is no guarrantee that your viewController  even deinits or your disposable types get disposed as well. They create a mutal like together via your `ViewMode` and all three objects stay in memory.

Take a look at [this](https://medium.com/zendesk-engineering/ios-identifying-memory-leaks-using-the-xcode-memory-graph-debugger-e84f097b9d15) article to see how to find memory leaks.